# good example on use of docker rest api

Tags: rest, api, docker

I can use docker commands on the command line. I also have some idea how to use python sdk to make docker calls. did not find a good way of using docker rest apis.  Tried this but it does not work. 
( it is from https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/examples/ ).
what is the id being mentioned here mean ? if i have to issue a rest api call to see "docker run hello-world" , what is to be done ?
is there some good documentation somewhere on rest apis. If there are good working examples on docker rest apis, it will be a good alternative python or similar sdks. 
( also, after receiving JSON response from rest api call, how do I process the JSON response ? any good document that explains this with working examples ? )

```
$ curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"Image": "alpine", "Cmd": ["echo", "hello world"]}' \
  -X POST http:/v1.24/containers/create
{"Id":"1c6594faf5","Warnings":null}

$ curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST http:/v1.24/containers/1c6594faf5/start

$ curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST http:/v1.24/containers/1c6594faf5/wait
{"StatusCode":0}

$ curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock "http:/v1.24/containers/1c6594faf5/logs?stdout=1"
hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

The API you want is [Docker Engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/)

It's almost always (!) better to use an SDK over a raw API.

SDKs represent best-practice use of the API, often include auth, logging etc. functionality, are often maintained, and often provide an abstraction over the underlying API.